# GnuPG / PGP front end for Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, gnupg

Is there a nice GnuPG/PGP front-end for Ubuntu? There used to be a package called something like seahorse-plugin, that let you right-click on files to encrypt them. I don't see it anymore in the software repository though. Is there something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04 the package is called `seahorse-nautilus`.

Comment: I'm on 11.10 currently, and that doesn't exist. Did they remove it for one release??

Comment: Yes, according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=seahorse I guess  because of the transition to Gnome3 the plugin wasn't available/working in time for 11.10

Answer (score 1):

If you're encrypting using keys, [pyrite](https://github.com/ryran/pyrite) is not as quick to use for files as the slick nautilus plugins, but you can check it out anyway.

PS: I'm the developer. Pyrite's a fully-functional gtk frontend for gpg/gpg2; just needs some nice icons/graphics and to be packaged up proper-like.